# No Such Element Exception

Tags: java, tokenize

I understand the no such element exception, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I need to use the Tokenizer so I can read the Tokens such as "A-902" or "S-823" and identify the character at 0 to determine which department the employee is in. The Information.txt contains entries like this:

Jane Rivers, A-902, 05/16/2001, 1, 16.25
Bob Cox, S-823, 06/21/1990, 2, 17.50

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{

        File newFile = new File("Information.txt");
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(newFile);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Department.txt");

        String[] employees = new String[9];

        while(readFile.hasNext()){

            for(int i=0; i<employees.length; i++){
                employees[i] = readFile.nextLine();
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<employees.length; k++){

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(employees[k],",");

        while(token.hasMoreTokens()){

                outFile.print(token.nextToken());

                if(token.nextToken().charAt(0)=='A'){
                    outFile.print(token.nextToken());
                    outFile.print("Accounting ");
                }else{

                if(token.nextToken().charAt(0)=='H'){
                    outFile.print(token.nextToken());
                    outFile.print("Human Resources ");
                }else{              

                if(token.nextToken().charAt(0)=='P'){
                    outFile.print(token.nextToken());
                    outFile.print("Production ");
                }else{              

                if(token.nextToken().charAt(0)=='S'){
                }
                    outFile.print(token.nextToken());
                    outFile.print("Shipping");
                }
                }
                }

        }
        }
        readFile.close();
        outFile.close();

    }



    }
```

Comment: Everytime you call `token.nextToken()` it will return you the next token and then advances to the next token ready to be called again. You probably want to call it only once per iteration.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `token.nextToken()` so many times in your `while` loop. That is what making the program go crazy.

You should just use it once, and store the result in temporary variable, and use it.

Comment: I thought that an If statement just checked the conditions? Thanks I'll work more on this.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus. Yeah you checked the condition for the next token only. But you are reading more than that.

Comment: Thanks again I will play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call token.nextToken(), you get the next token in the string that you tokenized. So in your code, you're checking against a different string in every if statement. What you need to do is just store the correct token and process that. Also, you know which token in the tokenizer has the data you want, so no need for a while loop, just go to the token you want. Finally, your if-else structure looks weird to me so I changed it around, unless I'm missing something what I've done below is the better way to do it. So replace your while loop with something like this:

```
String thisToken;

// the first token is the employee name so skip that one
token.nextToken();
// save the next token as its the one we want to look at
thisToken = token.nextToken();

outFile.print(thisToken);

if(thisToken.charAt(0)=='A'){
    outFile.print(thisToken);
    outFile.print("Accounting ");

}else if(thisToken.charAt(0)=='H'){
    outFile.print(thisToken);
    outFile.print("Human Resources ");

}else if(thisToken.charAt(0)=='P'){
    outFile.print(thisToken);
    outFile.print("Production ");

}else if(thisToken.charAt(0)=='S'){
    outFile.print(thisToken);
    outFile.print("Shipping");
}
```

Comment: You ARE! sloppy..., hehehe.. chill dude... you called `.nextToken` twice.

Comment: Ahh yes I see, an If/Else rather than nested if. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: haha sorry I posed that last answer when it was half done... This should solve your problem